# Wordpress MultiSite Individual Pages

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've setup WP multisite got it all working, but how do I create / show different pages per site?

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know how far have you got with it, so I will try to write simple instructions from the very start:

1. once installed, you go to /wp-admin, login as admin, then on the right of the scren you have the "Administration" link.
2. On the administration pages, you have "Blogs". Go there, create a blog ("Add Blog" a the bottom).
3. Once created, you will see the blog listed and a link to "Backend". Click there and you will access the blog's admin area, exactly the same as if it were a normal Wordpress blog.
4. To create new pages, go to Pages on the left menu, then "New page"...

The pages you create on one blog/site don't show on any other. Maybe you have only inserted pages on the main blog until now?

Comment: hey thanks, that sounds good, I'll take a look and get back to you. thanks for the quick reply